# Error during insert statement with SQLite3 in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, insert

I'm trying to insert some data in a SQLite 3 database in an iOS app. But i keep getting an error that is useless to me.

This is my code trying to insert:

```
 @try {
        NSString *dbPath = [self.GetDocumentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"knhb.sqlite"];
        BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
        if(!success)
        {
            NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
        }
        if((sqlite3_open_v2([dbPath UTF8String], &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL) != SQLITE_OK))
        {
            NSLog(@"An error has occured.");
        }


        NSString *sqlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO Profile (name, password) VALUES ('%@','%@')", name, password];

        const char *sql = [sqlString UTF8String];

        sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, 1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"%s SQLITE_ERROR '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(db), sqlite3_errcode(db));
        }

        sqlite3_step(sqlStatement);
        sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);

        int lastInsert = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(db);
        NSLog(@"lastinsertid:%d", lastInsert);

        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"An exception occured: %@", [exception reason]);
    }
```

My database table Profile has three columns idProfile, name and password. But since idProfile is an int and primary key I don't have to include it because it is auto incremented.

The error I keep getting is: SQLITE_ERROR 'near "I": syntax error' (1)

I am writing to the Documents folder.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Daan

Comment: You should not create the SQL statement using `stringWithFormat`. Make proper use of `sqlite3_bind_XXX` function calls to bind in the values. Perhaps your username or password have characters messing up the query. Properly binding the values will solve that kind of issue.

Comment: I've tried this, but I still get the same error. ('near "I": syntax error')

My code now:
const char *sql = "INSERT INTO Profile (name, password) VALUES (?,?)";
        
        sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
        
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, 1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"%s SQLITE_ERROR '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(db), sqlite3_errcode(db));
        }
        
        sqlite3_bind_text(sqlStatement, 1, [name UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(sqlStatement, 2, [password UTF8String], -2, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why but i fixed it by changing the following line of code:

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, 1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
```

i've turned it into:

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
```

Not sure what the 1 or -1 means. Maybe someone can elaborate?

Cheers!

Comment: Of course. I should have noticed that. See the docs for `sqlite3_prepare_v2`. The 3rd parameter is the string length for the query. You were stating that the string was only 1 character long. The -1 means that the length will be determined at runtime using `strlen`.